# What is the reason for page irresponsiveness?

Tags: javascript, firefox, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a developed a webpage which has more than 1100 lines of code, using JSF 2.0. 
That page also contains a lot of PrimeFaces components. I have also used JQuery to appear and disappear the components.

That webpage is responsive in the Firefox 4.0 and 3.16 browsers. But when I deployed that site in a server which has Firefox 3.05b, after doing some operations in that page which involves Ajax, said webpage seems to be sluggish and non responsive. Even the page could not be scrolled fast.

What may be the cause of this sluggishness? Is something related to JavaScript processing engine of the browser? Need some advise to overcome this frozen page. Thanks.

**Update:**

Here is the  [HTML Source](http://pastebin.com/SrGTLLp8) and [JSF Source](http://pastebin.com/Ni45G0R8)

Comment: We need some sample code or a URL to diagnose this.  PS is that 1,100 lines of JSF code? or it outputs 1,100 lines of HTML?

Comment: @scunliffe 590 lines of HTML code. Shall I post JSF code or HTML code?

Comment: I'd say the HTML is more helpful in this case (at least to start).  If you think the 590 lines might be a bit much for this page, you could always dump it into a http://pastebin.com/ and link to it.

Comment: I would like to see the jQuery, and an example of the specific code that is performing sluggishly.

Comment: @scunliffe I have posted the code of that page. Please see it. It goes 645 lines in patebin where as 590 lines in the browser in my system. Full of JavaSciript. Is that inefficient?

Comment: @James Wiseman gave a great answer below but I'd like to add that the generated HTML has some things that could be cleaned up. There's 12 external CSS stylesheets if these are all needed, try to combine them. Ditto for the 127 script tags/files ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe most of the CSS stylesheets and the Script tags are overhead of using primefaces and I dont think there is a way to combine or even touch them. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some code woulod be useful.

If the HTML document is large, then scanning/traversing the DOM using jQuery may be potentially costly.

jQuery Selectors are ranked by performance as follows:

1. #Id
2. Element
3. .class, :pseudoclass and :custom

The Class and PseudoClass and Custom selectors are slower than ID and Element selectors. The deficiency of their performance can be mitigated by combining them with other selector types, so do this wherever possible.

Examples:

```
$(".oddRows");                   //Inefficient: scans DOM for all elements with oddrows class
$("tr.oddRows");                 //More efficient: Searches only <tr>s with oddrows class
$("#MyTable tr.oddRows");        //More efficient: searches descendents of #MyTable
$("#MyTable>tbody>tr.oddRows");  //Best: searches immediate children
```

In these examples, we have combined CSS style selectors to obtain better performance in two ways:

- **Element.WithClass** – I.e. search for element with the specified class name
- **#Id Descendents** – I.e. search within descendents of the Id.
- **#Id>Children** – I.e. search only immediate children

The optimisation of selector performance is essential for efficient jQuery. This must be a major consideration for developers and code-reviewers alike.

**EDIT Re FireFox and JavaScript Speed**
There are several articles that suggest subsequent versions of FF have introduced performance enhancements:

3.1 - http://news.softpedia.com/news/Firefox-3-1-Gets-Major-JavaScript-Speed-Boost-92382.shtml

3.6. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/javascript-speedups-in-firefox-3-6/

Comment: Did you notice that the peculiarity of this problem. It runs smoothly on FF 3.16  or greater, and does not run responsively at lesser versions. Is the JavaScript processing power is low in FF 3.0? Should I use another browser?

Comment: Yes, I did. Edited to include links documenting JavaScript performance improvements in subsequent versions of FF